# .Net Deployment Project's Detected Dependencies magically un-excluded

Tags: .net, msbuild, dependencies, deployment-project

I have a Visual Studio 2005 .NET solution that has 20+ sub projects including a deployment project.  The VS2005 .NET deployment project has a number of detected dependences, that have been manually excluded and corrected values manually added in.

Sometimes however, these detected dependencies get magically un-excluded, which triggers a warning on the build:
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\')

What is the trigger that causes a detected dependency to be un-excluded?  Can deployment solutions have their warnings treated as errors so the nightly build won't proceed?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this???

Comment: I haven't found a better solution, so I suppose I am.  The re-inclusions aren't happening during the build.  We've had 3 or 4 developers have the re-inclusions happen at development time, and we've done a double take at some point and said how did THOSE come back.

Answer (score 1):

I have had that same issue and dealt with it for about a year before giving up and moving over to [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  It also did not help that I had to 'double-build' my builds because MSBuild for VS2005 will not work with deployment projects.

Anyway, you may want to consider something like WiX for your installs.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the dependent project has "Copy Local" set on a dependent DLL. The deployment/setup project has both the source and the copy of the DLL listed as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is more of a [hack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhx4ah11(VS.80).aspx) than anything else :)

You normally under visual studio have 2 options:

a) Exclude the duplicated DLLs

or
b) Set the **Condition** property of your duplicated DLLs to something different.

Problem is that with both of these approaches, you are still gonna have them **magically** reset and get the warning like before..

What worked for us is the following solution:

a) Go to your setup project and create a **Custom Folder**

b) Set the **DefaultLocation** property of your custom folder to be the same as the one you need those DLLs to be placed. ie for ASP.NET applications the value is [TARGETDIR]\bin

c) Then drag and drop ALL the duplicated dlls into this folder and you should get no warnings now.

That's it. You should get no warnings for those dlls, if you have any extra just drag them into this folder.

Hope this helps.

-Konstantinos

Comment: Problem with that is that you'll still be copying 2 files over, one of which may be different, (which is probably why you get the warning)

Answer (score 0):

The discussion of detected dependency refreshes here may explain the behavior if you're using multiple development environments with the same project:

http://www.xmission.com/~legalize/msi/known-bugs-2003.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm using VS-2005 and it appears the first two issues in your link have not been addressed in VS-2005.  Who knows about 2008 and beyond...